# Download file directly to a remote machine

Tags: ssh, downloads, ftp, nfs, remote

Is there any possibility to download a file to some remote machine which has ftp, ssh, nfs access. What I mean is that it doesn't have to go through the machine from which the download is issued.

Comment: This question does not make sense as-is.  Where is the file that you want to download?  How would you normally download that file?

Comment: Sorry, I kinda found the answer, but I don't know how to automate it. THe file is on the web, e.g., I saw that one could ssh into remote machine and then wget it. Of course, automate it from the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if it has ssh, you can always ssh the remote machine, and execute the following command to download a file directly to that machine

```
wget <link_of_file_to_download>
```

for example, to download a tux picture whose link i know into a server of mine, i would do the following commands

```
ssh user@myserver
wget http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Tux.svg/170px-Tux.svg.png
```

Comment: True, Sam, that is exactly the procedure. It would be great if that could be done ONLY from firefox!

Comment: there *might* be a plugin for firefox, tho i havent searched for one

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you're asking - download a file in a browser on machine A, but save it to a disk on machine B - you will need a network connection between machines A and B (which means a VPN, if they're not on the same local network) and then you'll need to mount a disk from machine B on machine A.

This last bit can be done with nfs, samba, sshfs, or any number of other ways.  We need more info before we can specify something more directly.

Comment: by doing that, even if the file is  not saved on computer A, the file still goes through computers A and B and if i understand correctly, the op wants to download it directly to computer B without passing through A

Answer (score 0):

You could always use secure copy,

Uploading local file to remote server via ssh;

```
scp /source/of/file username@remoteserver:/destination/file
```

Downloading from a remote server to a local directory

```
scp username@remoteserver:/destination/file /source/of/file
```

Download from a remote server and upload to another remote server

```
scp username@remoteserver:/destination/file username2@remoteserver2:/destinatio/file2
```

Remembering you can also pass options if you would like to recursively upload/download a directory!

Hope this helped.